# How to make an image co-exist on same line as text in RTF

Tags: perl, rtf

I am using Perl RTF::Writer to insert an image at the center of a page with descriptive text at the left side. Like this dummy image:

[image: sample RTF structure]

I'm able to format the text perfectly, but I so far cannot get the image to co-exist on the same line with text. The image wants to be the only object on that line and bumps any text on its line down to the bottom of the image.

Here's the code I'm trying so far:

```
$rtf->paragraph(
    \'\qc\ul\f0\fs28\b',
    "Sugar Maple\n");
$rtf->paragraph(
    \'\lc\f0\fs24\plain', 
    "Common name: $ID\nScientific Name: $sciname", 
    $rtf->image('filename' => "$pngName"),"\nDistribution: Eastern US");
 $rtf->close;
```

But this results in "Distribution" being located at the bottom of the image. How can I adjust this code to make the left-aligned text in line with the center-aligned image?

Comment: What's with the backslash in front of the first quote in the `paragraph` call? First argument, `\'\qc\ul\f0\fs28\b'`.

Comment: That was included in the usage example from the documentation. Deleting it results in "\qc\ul\f0\fs28\bSugar Maple" being printed to the document, so it must indicate formatting rather than literal text.

Comment: It hasn't thrown any syntax errors from that so far. I thought it was weird too. The RTF::Writer CPAN page doesn't talk much about why it's there (at least I didn't see it).

Comment: Oh. Never mind. It's a reference to the string. The weird highlighting here confused me. The first arg needs to be a scalar ref. My bad.